# Does a JavaScript for-loop redeclare the variable in each iteration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop, closures

I am trying to understand closures in JavaScript and came across this example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const log = () => {
        console.log(i);
    };
    setTimeout(log, 100);
}
```

Since the variable `i` is scoped to the `for` loop, a new reference is being given to it in each iteration, so it is not shared between iterations, so the closure captures the `log` function along with the reference to the `i` variable in each iteration.

as expected the output is:

```
$ 0
$ 1
$ 2
```

However, in the following snippet the behavior is different:

```
for (let arr = [1, 2, 3]; arr.length !== 0; arr.pop()) {
    const log = () => {
        console.log(arr);
    };
    setTimeout(log, 1000);
}
```

The expected output is

```
$ [1, 2, 3]
$ [1, 2]
$ [1]
```

But i got 3 logs with an empty array, this suggests that the `arr` variable might be shared between iterations.

Comment: There's only one `arr` *(a reference to an array)* and it's modified *(emptied w/ pops)* before any of the timers will fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `arr` variable is initialized on each iteration of the loop to a *reference* to the array. It is indeed a different variable on each iteration, but there's only one array, and your loop pops a value off on every iteration. Thus by the time the timers fire, the array is empty.

The precise details of how a locally-scoped variable in a `for` loop works are kind-of complicated. The initialization expression is evaluated once (I'm pretty sure; the spec is hard to read), and then on each iteration a new variable is created and initialized to the value of the previous one. Thus, the direct value of the variable doesn't change in the case of an array reference. If you could do a "last_variable === this_variable" test somehow (you can't), it would be `true` between iterations, because it's the same array. But with a primitive value, it wouldn't be the same.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for, in each iteration the `arr` variable has a new reference but the value (which is the adress of the first element of the array) is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is, i is an integer, passed as copy parameter to another function. arr is an array passed as reference parameter.

So after the timeout, the copy did not change even if the original value changed, but the referenced have changed.

[https://javascript.info/object-copy#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20fundamental%20differences,%E2%80%9Cas%20a%20whole%20value%E2%80%9D](https://javascript.info/object-copy#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20fundamental%20differences,%E2%80%9Cas%20a%20whole%20value%E2%80%9D).